# Angular ng-options not update select list when the ng-options model updates

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm using angular 1.4.12, and I need a select menu in my application.
i'm using ng-options with an array of object populated from an async function, but the SELECT does not see the update and after that is still empty. I tried with "track by", but it does not work.
Any advice? thanks!

Comment: You are probably going to have to share some code. If you could replicate the issue in jsFiddle then that would be even better

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/halirgb/Lvc0u55v/ there is the jsFiddle, the problem is only when the ng-options array is empty at start

Comment: Are you sure that is the right fiddle? It doesnt have any uses of ng-option on it

Comment: sorry, wrong link: http://jsfiddle.net/andrear86/Lvc0u55v/8989/

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems here

Firstly, the selectors on the ng-options are a little more complex than a simple binding.

Secondly, try to avoid using setTimeout when developing with angular. Angular bindings know to update because of a process called the digest cycle. During this process bindings are evaluated and checked for changes. This process is triggered internally from angular, and it happens a lot.

The problem however is that setTimeout, because it is not part of angular, doesnt trigger a digest. So the bindings on your option box would never update. To combat this, angular provides its own timeout helper. $timeout.

Please see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8992/) for a working solution.

The ng-options needs to be updated to something like this. You can read more about ng-options [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem.label for item in items" ng-model="model">
</select>
```

And your controller needs to inject $timeout for reasons mentioned above

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.name = 'Try';
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.model = {};

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.items = [
        {subItem: {value: "a", label: "1"}},
        {subItem: {value: "b", label: "2"}},
      ];
      alert($scope.items.length);
    }, 2000);
}
```

UPDATE:
As mentioned in the comments below, using an external library with its own async operations can cause aditional angular digest issues. A simple solution to this is to use angulars promise library, $q. I have updated the fiddler to contain an example of this. [Click here to see it](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8996/)

The updated code is as follows

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $q, $timeout) {
    $scope.name = 'Try';
    $scope.items = [];
    $scope.model = {};

    function myPromise(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //Do your pouchDB request here and then call resolve in the pouchDB callback
        $timeout(() => {
            deferred.resolve("This would be your results object");
        }, 2000)

        return deferred.promise;    
    }

    myPromise().then((results) => {
          $scope.items = [
          {subItem: {value: "a", label: "1"}},
          {subItem: {value: "b", label: "2"}},
        ];
        alert(results);
    });
}
```

Comment: i don't use setTimeout in my code, i'm using PouchDB, but the data I need in the ng-object is retrived in an async way,so I used setTimeout in the fiddle. after the PouchDB query, i tried to call $rootScope.$apply() in the callback of the Pouch promise, but it does not work

Comment: Please see the above edit. Essentially using promises should be able to help you

Comment: Did that help at all?

Comment: Someway: I found that the problem was in the select-picker library :(